# gene expression fold change threshold limit

Tags: pcr

When interpreting qRT-PCR results, which results are acceptable as fold changes, which are acceptable for housekeeping genes? e.j. a values of 0.8 raw fold changes for a "housekeeping" gene is acceptable as such? and conversely which is the threshold to say that there was "fold change"?

Comment: What do you mean by "raw fold"? Values not normalized to the normalization gene?

Comment: yes, values not normalised to any housekeeping

Comment: Why not? This will make comparisions hard to impossible.

Comment: please clarify, what are you answering to

Comment: Why didn't you normalize your genes?

Comment: because my housekeeping gene got a 20% fold reduction under the experimental treatment

Comment: What is the difference in your gene of interest between treated and untreated? Fluctuations in housekeeping genes can (and do) happen and are not necessarily due to the experiment. Thats why I usually test two stable genes if possible.

Comment: as i already wrote i got a 20% reduction = 0.8 fold change treatment/control

Comment: Ahh, I thought this was only for the housekeeping gene. If both are reduced by the same amount, this will be difficult.

Comment: sorry i misread before. well i had 3 genes of interest and the results varied: 2 got upregulation of %20, other %100. the housekeeping nevertheless was downregulated at %20 under treatment

Comment: So now you have two possibilities to choose from: First it is very possible that your housekeeping gene varies a bit because of slightly different experimental conditions (cells a bit more dense, slightly more metabolism and so on). In this case you can correct for this and your values can be used. Second it can be, that your treatment also affected the housekeeping gene. If this happens you need to choose another housekeeping gene for normalization which is not affected. If the first is true (and I tend to think so) this correction can be done in a software like REST2009.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in your previous post. If your reference gene undergoes changes then replace it with another reference and if even that doesn't work out then use a spike in. You **must** normalize. Interpreting the raw values can be erroneous- there could be a loading bias. Don't think much- repeating RNA isolation and/or qPCR is not a very hard job. And as Chris said, use two references if you can.

*BTW, if you are fine with it then can you tell what is the gene that you are studying and what is the treatment*

**w.r.t what is a significant fold change.**

There is no hard and fast rule to determine what is an acceptable fold change. In some robust systems a minor perturbation in the gene expression will not translate to any great biological outcome whereas there can be sensitive systems in which minor changes can affect the cell state. These things depend on how the gene is integrated in the regulatory network.